# Update statement with concat & inner join on Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, concatenation

I'm trying to create an update query that concatenates 3 fields from a table to 1 field in another table

The first table called table1

```
ID       DESC
12       left:Middle:Right
```

The second table Table 2

```
ID  FLD1    FLD2    FLD3
12  left    Middle  Right
```

Trying to update all the desc field on Table1 with the values of table2 where table1.id = table2.id

```
update table1 A SET A.DESC = (SELECT CONCAT(B.fld1, ':', B.fld2, ':', B.fld3) 
                              from table2 B 
                              where A.ID = B.ID) 
Where A.id = 12;
```

However, I'm getting an error from the above query saying "invalid number of arguments" Any idea what am I doing wrong? or how can I get this done in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONCAT` accepts only two parameters, which means that you have to use nested `CONCAT`s.

Though, you'd rather use the double pipe `||` operator which doesn't have such a restriction. So:

```
update table1 A SET A.DESC = (SELECT B.fld1 ||':'|| B.fld2 ||':'|| B.fld3   --> this
                              from table2 B 
                              where A.ID = B.ID) 
Where A.id = 12;
```

---

To update all matching rows, you could

```
update table1 A SET A.DESC = (SELECT B.fld1 ||':'|| B.fld2 ||':'|| B.fld3   --> this
                              from table2 B 
                              where A.ID = B.ID) 
Where exists (select null
              from table2 b
              where a.id = b.id);
```

or `MERGE`:

```
merge into table1 a
  using table2 b
  on (b.id = a.id)
  when matched then update set a.desc = b.fld1 ||':'|| b.fld2 ||':'|| b.fld3;
```

---

As you got duplicates, `DISTINCT` might help, e.g.

```
update table1 a set 
  a.desc = (select distinct b.fld1 ||':'|| b.fld2 ||':'|| b.fld3
            from table2 b
            where a.id = b.id
           )
where exists ...
```

If not, then you'll have to see what to do with these duplicates. If possible, use yet another column(s) in `WHERE` clause. Or, if you don't really care which concatenated combination fits, use aggregate function(s) such as `MIN` or `MAX`, e.g.

```
update table1 a set 
  a.desc = (select max(b.fld1 ||':'|| b.fld2 ||':'|| b.fld3)
            from table2 b
            where a.id = b.id
           )
where exists ...
```

Comment: ok, That fixed the issue with updating the concat. however, how can I extend this to update all the table.  instead of A.id = 12   ... I tried A.id = B.id;  but it's throwing an error. any idea how to make it to update all?

Comment: I added some more examples; have a look, please.

Comment: from the update I got the following "single-row subquery returns more than one row"...
from the merge I got the followin error "unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables"...

Comment: That's because there are duplicates; IDs aren't *unique*. Try to add DISTINCT, *maybe* it'll help. Added those examples as well.